# Which test to choose for these series and why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Which convergence test we need to choose for these two equations?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{10+k^{2}}\tag{1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}{4^{k}\, k!}\tag{2}$$

For $(1)$ I think integral test as it is easy to integrate.
For $(2)$ I think ratio test.
Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: The first does definitely not converge. $k/(10+k^2)\sim k/k^2=1/k$.

Comment: so for First I will use Integral...as for second I think ratio

Comment: I would use the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) for the first one.

Comment: They are both different equations...they both do not relate to each other

Comment: Yes... I know, that's why I said for the first one. Compare $a_k = k/(10+k^2)$ and $b_k = 1/k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use direct comparison in both cases.

In the first case:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{10+k^{2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10/k+k}\ge \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10+k},$$ from where the series is divergent.

In the second case:

$$0\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1.3.5..(2k+1)}{4^{k} k!}\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^k}{4^{k}},$$ from where it follows that the series is convergent.

(Note that

$$\frac{1\cdot 3 \cdots (2k+1)}{1\cdot 2 \cdots k}=\frac{3}{1}\frac{5}{2}\cdots \frac{2k+1}{k}\le 3^k.)$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first one is divergent.

The second one is convergent since $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}= \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2k+3}{4(k+1)}= \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: can we do it using ratio comparison

Comment: ofcourse...since they are positive series.